# Convert Decimal Degrees to Decimal Minutes with two digit minute

Tags: excel

I'm using the following excel formula to convert Decimal Degrees to Decimal Minutes. It's working fine for me, only one issue.  The (mins) need to be a two digit number for my GPS to take it.  This is what its doing now 83°3.4940-W
and What I need is 83°03.4940-W .  I need the zero in front of single digit numbers.

Here is what I'm using now.

```
=CONCATENATE(TRUNC(ABS(B2)),"°",FIXED((ABS(B2)-TRUNC(ABS(B2)))*60,4),"-W")
```

B2 cell contains the position is decimal deg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXT():

```
=CONCATENATE(TRUNC(ABS(B2)),"°",TEXT(FIXED((ABS(B2)-TRUNC(ABS(B2)))*60,4),"00.0000"),"-W")
```

Comment: Works great only one problem,  If the minute is 0 it only puts one zero... Thoughts?